# ERROR creating IPsets 'WAFLimitsExceededException'

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-application-firewall

I'm creating an AWS WAFV2 configuration (IP sets, webacls ..) with python and boto3.

I executed it and it worked at first but then I deleted from the console all the created resources and executed the script again but I got this error :

**" botocore.errorfactory.WAFLimitsExceededException: An error occurred (WAFLimitsExceededException) when calling the CreateIPSet operation: AWS WAF couldn’t perform the operation because you exceeded your resource limit "**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to put some delay before executing subsequent API calls because there's API call limit:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/limits.html

> Maximum number of calls to any individual Create, Put, or Update action, if no other quota is defined for it
>   **One request per second**